# How to display/save multiple (ADF) WIA images after scanned

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I was tasked with creating a document digitizing program since the one the company bough borders on the awful. Its bad. Really bad. After some research I started a VB.NET WPF program. I already made login section and created the folders in a server where the files will be going, with the location of each file being saved in a SQL table. Anyway I basically need three things that are giving me a headache!

1) How to scan multiple pages with WIA? This is my current, and very raw scanning code:

```
    Dim CD As New WIA.CommonDialog
    Dim txt As String
    Dim picture As Image

    Dim F As WIA.ImageFile = CD.ShowAcquireImage(WIA.WiaDeviceType.ScannerDeviceType)
    txt = txt1.Text
    F.SaveFile("\\serverlocation" + txt + "." + F.FileExtension)
```

Txt is basically the name being given by the user. The problem is that this code only scans ONE page, how can I make it save multiple ones in the same file/separate files? (whichever works best).

1. In the same spirit of the previous question, is there a way to convert these files to JPEG/PNG (BMP takes a LOT of space) or even convert them to a PDF file if the user so wishes?
2. How do I display the scanned picture after its been scanned?

I am using VB.NET and WPF (not Forms). Any replies will be greatly appreciated :).

EDIT: Closest thing I've managed to multiple ADF scanning with http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?439027-Windows-Image-Acquisition-%28WIA%29-Code . I converted C# to VB but the code throws me errors in the compiler.

Comment: If you're doing WPF, then you'd rather also do MVVM. That's the best way to get clean code, and do less code to get more results.

Comment: I will be playing around with it. I am getting used to the "paradigm" shift to these type of models.

Comment: in WPF, whenever you need N `Items` of anything (regardless of what that thing is), you can use an `ItemsControl`.

Comment: Soooo.... I guess ADF WIA is somewhat pretty hard for VB right? I am screwed. I can't find anything that works online, surprisingly. Wow.

Comment: All I've found are third party alternatives and non working codes. I am pretty close to giving up :P!

Comment: what did you do in the end? i have now the same requirements now

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Function scanMe(ByVal myDPI As Integer, ByVal myHeight As Double, ByVal myWidth As Double, ByVal ShowSelectScanner As Boolean, ByVal ShowScanPreview As Boolean) As Byte()
    Dim CD As New WIA.CommonDialog
    Dim device As WIA.Device = CD.ShowSelectDevice(WIA.WiaDeviceType.ScannerDeviceType, ShowSelectScanner, False)
    Dim item As WIA.Item = device.Items(1)
    Try
        With item
            .Properties("Horizontal Resolution").Value = myDPI
            .Properties("Vertical Resolution").Value = myDPI
            .Properties("Horizontal Extent").Value = myDPI * myWidth
            .Properties("Vertical Extent").Value = myDPI * myHeight
        End With
        Dim F As WIA.ImageFile

        If ShowScanPreview Then
            F = CD.ShowAcquireImage(WiaDeviceType.ScannerDeviceType, WiaImageIntent.ColorIntent, WiaImageBias.MaximizeQuality, WIA.FormatID.wiaFormatBMP, False, True, False)
        Else
            F = CD.ShowTransfer(item, WIA.FormatID.wiaFormatPNG, False)
        End If

        Dim myBuffer As Byte() = F.FileData.BinaryData
        Return myBuffer
    Catch ex As Exception

        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: explain some about your answer